# Is there any way to achive frost glass effect in custom rounded button?

Tags: android, button, libraries, shapes, blurry

I am trying to implement custom shaped button with frost glass effect on it. I've used all libraries which i've found but i was able to achieve the mentioned effect only for rectangular views.
Is there any library which could help me?

My button layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/white">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#80ABABAB"></solid>
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Answer (score -1):

No need for library. You are using `android:shape="rectangle"` what you should use is `android:shape="oval"`

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@android:color/white">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
        <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#80ABABAB"></solid>
        <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```